# Call on page fancybox link with javascript function

Tags: javascript, class, redirect, fancybox

I am trying to call an existing fancybox link on my page with a javascript function embedded in a button link.

The working fancybox link on my page looks something like this:

```
<a id="item1" class="inline show_form" href="http://link.com">Link</a>
```

The button from where I try to call this link via a javascript function looks like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $button_url; ?>" onclick=test(); class="button"></a>
```

The javascript function I have now, is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"><!-- function test() {
  window.location.href = "http://link.com"
}
--></script>
```

So when I now click the button, it actually opens $button_url in a new window, while redirecting the current browser window to http://link.com. However, I'd like to have http://link.com opened in a fancybox window. Any of you guys know how to change my javascript to make this link use the fancybox class from the page: class="inline show_form"?

Comment: What does `$button_url` return? because I think you should rather trigger a `click` on the `$(".inline show_form")` selector (if that selector is bound to fancybox) using either the `href` or the `onclick` attributes of the button.

Comment: `$button_url` returns the product url, depending on which product page the button is located. The desired behavior by clicking that button is: the product url is loaded in a new browser window AND the current browser window gets redirected to another url opening in a fancybox. So only thing I am missing now is having [link]http://link.com[link] opened in a fancybox. The `class="inline show_form"` selector is indeed bound to fancybox, any idea how I can alter my `window.location.href = "http://link.com"` to make it used that selector?